# Insert multiple data separated with comma in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna ask how to insert multiple data with comma, I have a data like this :

```
$fruits = 'apple, banana, grape';
$beverages = 'coffee, tea, juice';
```

then I wan to insert the data in one action

here my code

```
$arr = explode(',', $fruits);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
  $item = array(
  'fruits'   => $fruits[$i],
  'beverages' => $beverages[$i],
);

$this->db->insert('tb_menu', $item);
}
```

it's not working, then I use print_r the data displaying like this

```
Array ( [fruits] => a [beverages] => c ) Array ( [fruits] => p [beverages] => o ) Array ( [fruits] => p [beverages] => f )
```

anyone know how to handle this? Plz help me!!

Comment: You want to store all data in single column?

Comment: no, the data is insert to each column, sorry my English is bad.

Comment: What exactly you want to do. Do you want to save whole data in single column or separate column for each fruit and  beverages

Comment: separate column for each fruits and beverages, sorry my english is really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code.

```
$fruits = 'apple, banana, grape';
$beverages = 'coffee, tea, juice';
$fruitsArray = explode(',', $fruits);
$beveragesArray = explode(',', $beverages);

for($i = 0; $i < count($fruitsArray); $i++)
{

    $item = array('fruits' => $fruitsArray[$i],'beverages' => $beveragesArray[$i]);
    $this->db->insert('tb_menu', $item);

}
```

try this may it helps you. one thing both string contain no of comma separated value same. otherwise there may be chance to skip for some values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode(',', $fruits);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

  $item = array('fruits'   => $fruits[$i],'beverages' => $beverages[$i]);
  $this->db->insert('tb_menu', $item[i]);//add index 

}
```

//try this it may be work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You have to create two arrays for both fruits and beverages. In our case both array have same length so we will loop through any one. Then insert each and every index of array in Database.

```
$arr = explode(',', $fruits);
$arr1 = explode(',', $beverages);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
  $item = array(
  'fruits'   => $arr[$i],
  'beverages' => $arr1[$i],
   );

$this->db->insert('tb_menu', $item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this separately:

```
$fruits = 'apple, banana, grape';
$fruitsArray = explode(',', $fruits);
foreach ($fruitsArray as $row) {              
      $fruit['fruits'] = $row;
      $this->db->insert('tb_menu', $fruit);  
}
```